# Stability of a really dense galaxy

Tags: science-based, gravity, astrophysics

How stable would a galaxy where everything is very close by be? Would solar systems be able to exist (long enough for humanoid organisms to evolve)?

By close, I mean that the distance between two adjacent star systems is around one or two light years. Everything is (roughly) evenly distributed

Comment: Stars are a lot closer near the center of the galaxy and more spread out as you move outwards. Stars near galactic center can be very close to each other. You really can't get a galaxy where the distribution is even because naturally the center is more dense than the surrounding.

Comment: Important reading when you start putting stars closer together: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_habitable_zone . Higher density of stars means more radiation, different distribution of elements, and more frequent life-killing nearby supernovae.

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25706/what-is-the-density-of-stars-near-the-center-of-the-milky-way

Comment: @user535733: That link basically has the answer. *'...and the nearest star would most likely be less than 1 light-year away'*

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have with this galactic density isn't planet formation or even gravitational interference; it's super novas and asteroids.

Our solar system is on the edge of the Milky Way galaxy, relatively speaking. This is a good thing for us because the stars are more spread out and therefore will have less of an effect on us should one decide to explode. In point of fact, our rotation around the galactic core isn't two dimensional; we actually wobble up and down through the spiral as well. There is some [compelling evidence](http://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2013/09/30/3857090.htm) that all of the mass extinctions that have occurred on Earth have been as a result of the solar system transitioning through the arm proper of the Milky Way. This seems to happen every 30 million years ago, and it last happened about 1 million years ago. Good news for us.

It is generally thought that life is highly unlikely to form in the galactic core because of the density and the higher chances of stars going nova close to yours. If Barnard's Star (for example) went nova, our proximity to it would likely destroy all life on Earth, regardless of where we are in our galactic 'wobble'.

Also, I have to challenge this idea of everything being evenly distributed in a galaxy. Galaxies just don't work that way. Generally speaking you have a super-massive black hole at the centre, and everything else is held in an orbit around this with locally concentrated areas around either smaller black holes or other very heavy dense objects.

One of the reasons that we've been so successful on Earth is that we're away from the madding crowd of the Galaxy, and we have Jupiter in the solar system cleaning up most of the stray asteroids and debris before it can enter the inner solar system and be a risk to us. Your proposed galactic model would make life rather difficult because it takes literally billions of years to form intelligent life (based on a sample set of one) but only one quick event to wipe it out in all that time. That event is far more likely to occur in your model.